# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond level

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, iis-10

There are multiple errors here but i think root of the problem is the title above

When I try to run the website from Visual Studio for the first time without opening any of the files it runs but on the browser it says:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

then after opening the web.config file this appears.

```
Error   90  It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  C:\EMBRAER_LMS\ST-PAF\Setup&Maintenance\Site\web.config 102
```

I tried loading it to IIS Manager and loading it like this

[image]

making the main folder to be a virtual directory and making the folder inside it a application. when running it from IIS manager with the ASP.NET Impersonation Enabled it will tell me to Disable it and shows the error meesage:

```
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Most likely causes:
system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.
```

when I try to run it while ASP.NET is disabled it will show

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I tried changing my dns from 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 to 1.1.1.1 / 1.1.0.0 and nothing happened ive been trying to make this work for the last couple of days but being stuck at these errors. this website was only pass to me and have no prior background to asp.net

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis ASP.NET web apps cannot be deployed as virtual directories.

Comment: what should i do then?

Comment: If you want to publish asp.net to iis, you can refer to this link: [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis).